# Why are Phillip's unmarried daughters mentioned in acts 21?

Tags: acts, prophecy

Acts 21:9

> He had four unmarried daughters, who prophesied.

Why are there 4?
And why are they unmarried?
And why are they included in the Scripture?

Seems like a fun family, but a bit of jarring detail when reading the passage narratively.

Comment: It is a very interesting info about that man, the context is clear. Nothing cryptic and symbolic about it, nor about the girls being virgin.

Comment: The point about being unmarried or virgin daughters may be that this would suggest that they lived in their father Philip's home.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Luke's method is to name his sources and where they can be found - he does this throughout:

- the Gospel of Luke, much of which is organized by geography, cites the towns Jesus visited and calls out, very often by name, the people who can attest to the works performed and teachings given there (the trip to Jericho in Luke 19 being a classic example)
- the Book of Acts, much of which reads like a travel log, citing the places the apostles traveled to, key events that happened there, and again, very often citing by name the people who can attest to these events.

It is as if Luke is challenging his reader to go fact check him.

The daughters of Philip (or at least some of them) were still around when Acts was written and could be contacted if anyone wanted to verify Luke's story. In fact, Papias, an early Bishop of Hieropolis, reported that he had met some of the daughters of Philip (this would be a few decades after Acts was written), and that they were a significant source of knowledge about first-generation Christianity (see Eusebius *Church History* 3.39.9).

Luke mentions them because they are an important primary source.

Comment: Same with Paul on the witnesses to Christ's resurrection in 1 Corinthians 15:6.

Comment: Same as Paul in 1 Corinthians 15:6 re witnesses to the resurrection of Jesus

Comment: Last comment from davidgeorgecarr@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

Surely Luke mentions them because he wants to report the fact that they prophesied.

This will have been a frequent event (imperfect tense), and the fact that women prophesied is something we want to know about today. But perhaps like Agabus in the next couple of verses they all prophesied on this occasion about what would happen at the end of the journey.

Their single status explains why they are still living with Philip instead of with their husbands.

There are four of them because that's how it goes. In those days, people had children until they stopped coming. My ancestor Walter Abbott (born 1834) had four daughters among his fifteen children by two wives

Luke has been reporting this whole sea-journey in more detail than might be strictly necessary (the fact that he went from Cos to Rhodes is of interest now only to the social and economic historians) because the events at the end of the journey give it a greater signficance. He says "we", which implies that he was one of the passengers.

Answer (score 1):

First the word is not **unmarried** but **virgins** παρθένοι ([G3933](https://biblehub.com/greek/parthenoi_3933.htm))

> Now this man had four virgin daughters who were prophetesses. [Acts 21:9 NASB](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=acts%2021%3A9&version=NASB)

And if we look back to the earlier female prophetesses Miriam, Deborah & Huldah.

> **Miriam the prophetess**, Aaron’s sister, took the tambourine in her
> hand, and all the women went out after her with tambourines and with
> dancing. [Exodus 15:20](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Exodus%2015%3A20&version=nasb)

> Now **Deborah, a prophetess**, the wife of Lappidoth, was judging
> Israel at that time. [Judges 4:4](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=judges%204%3A4&version=NASB)

> So Hilkiah the priest, Ahikam, Achbor, Shaphan, and Asaiah went to
> **Huldah the prophetess**, the wife of Shallum the son of Tikvah, the son of Harhas, keeper of the wardrobe (and she lived in Jerusalem in
> the Second Quarter); and they spoke to her. [2 Kings 22:14](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2%20Kings%2022%3A14&version=NASB)

They are all female adults and it's significant that young women start to prophecies in the name of the Lord and it's a prophecy being fullfilled;

> It will come about after this
> That I will pour out My Spirit on all mankind;
> And your sons and **your daughters will prophesy**,
> Your old men will have dreams,
> Your young men will see visions. [Joel 2:28](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Joel%202%3A28&version=NASB)

Answer (score 1):

The Scripture does not answer this question so any suggestions must, to a certain extent, be at least a little speculative.  Here are my suggestion reasons for this being part of the inspired record.

Acts 21:9 about 4 virgin (not unmarried) daughters of Philip being prophets:

- it shows that spiritual gifts, including prophecy, we active in the local church
- such prophets delivered messages that did not become part of the NT canon.  (That is, being a prophet did not necessarily mean that one's message would be included in the canon of Scripture.)
- it showed that women could be a very important, God-ordained part of church life, ministry and operation
- it showed that women did not have to be married in order to have some importance (neither did men such as Paul)
- the fact that these women delivered God's messages means that they spoke in church and presumably had significant roles in meetings

That is, Acts 21:9 is included not so much to round out the narrative, but to add an important detail about the functioning of the NT church and thus, leave an important series of messages for later generations.

The comments from the Cambridge commentary may be helpful:

> The family of the Evangelist were walking in their father’s steps.
> These daughters, instead of resting at home, took upon them the hard
> duty of publishing the message of the Gospel. The English word
> “prophesy” has come to have, since about the beginning of the
> seventeenth century, only the one sense of “to predict what is yet to
> come.” In the time of Queen Elizabeth “prophesyings” meant
> “preachings,” and Jeremy Taylor’s famous work on the “Liberty of
> Prophesying,” was written to uphold the freedom of preaching. These
> women were, in their degree, Evangelists also.

Comment: I can see how certain times and cultures would be aided by referencing normalized female leadership from the text. However, assuming the function `prophecy = preaching` is nonsensical, regardless of what level of civil authority you carry.

Comment: @KeenanDiggs - are you suggesting that prophets did not preach?

Comment: No, rather that prophecy and preaching are not the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Remember the gospel of Luke, the first episode of Acts, Luke wrote

> Luke 1:1 Inasmuch as many have undertaken to compile a narrative of the things that have been accomplished among us, 2 just as those who from the beginning were eyewitnesses and ministers of the word have delivered them to us, 3 it seemed good to me also, **having followed all things closely for some time past, to write an orderly account for you**, most excellent Theophilus, 4 that you may have certainty concerning the things you have been taught.

Therefore the account of Philip and the Ethiopian (Acts 8:26-40), was a first-handed account that Luke directly heard from Philip, about his evangelic journey. The ending of this account said;

> Acts 8:40 - Philip, however, appeared at Azotus and traveled about, preaching the gospel in all the towns until he reached **Caesarea**.

And Caesarea was where Luke and Paul met Philip in Acts 21. Though the scripture only had a short account of their gathering, but I would imagine that Luke was very impressed by his four daughters, that Luke had a long talk with Philip of his evangelic journey, and discovered his account with the Ethiopian.

Why are Philip's unmarried daughters mentioned? It was because Luke was initially impressed by them, then from Philip he discovered further more about the marvellous story of him with the Ethiopian.

Answer (score 0):

Narratively, it is a way of picking up an Old Testament theme and bringing it into the New Testament.

The theme is that of women receiving an inheritance. Their prophesying is evidence of the Holy Spirit, who, according to Paul (in Ephesians 1:13-14, 2 Corinthians 1:22, and Corinthians 5:5), is a guarantee of inheritance.

It contrasts with the story of the 5 daughters of Zelophehad (Numbers 27:1-11).

> <sup>**1**</sup> The daughters of Zelophehad son of Hepher, the son of Gilead, the son of Makir, the son of Manasseh, belonged to the clans of Manasseh son of Joseph. The names of the daughters were Mahlah, Noah, Hoglah, Milkah and Tirzah. They came forward <sup>**2**</sup> and stood before Moses, Eleazar the priest, the leaders and the whole assembly at the entrance to the tent of meeting and said, <sup>**3**</sup> “Our father died in the wilderness. He was not among Korah’s followers, who banded together against the Lord, but he died for his own sin and left no sons. <sup>**4**</sup> Why should our father’s name disappear from his clan because he had no son? Give us property among our father’s relatives.”
>
> <sup>**5**</sup> So Moses brought their case before the Lord, <sup>**6**</sup> and the Lord said to him, <sup>**7**</sup> “What Zelophehad’s daughters are saying is right. You must certainly give them property as an inheritance among their father’s relatives and give their father’s inheritance to them.
>
> <sup>**8**</sup> “Say to the Israelites, ‘If a man dies and leaves no son, give his inheritance to his daughter. <sup>**9**</sup> If he has no daughter, give his inheritance to his brothers. <sup>**10**</sup> If he has no brothers, give his inheritance to his father’s brothers. <sup>**11**</sup> If his father had no brothers, give his inheritance to the nearest relative in his clan, that he may possess it. This is to have the force of law for the Israelites, as the Lord commanded Moses.’”

In this section, the Law sees inheritance as a finite resource, and its recipients are given it according to a predetermined hierarchy, and there is no record of whether much blessing was generated from it.

However, it compares with the story of Job's 3 daughters (Job 42:12-15):

> <sup>**12**</sup> The Lord blessed the latter part of Job’s life more than the former part. He had fourteen thousand sheep, six thousand camels, a thousand yoke of oxen and a thousand donkeys. <sup>**13**</sup> And he also had seven sons and three daughters. <sup>**14**</sup> The first daughter he named Jemimah, the second Keziah and the third Keren-Happuch. <sup>**15**</sup> Nowhere in all the land were there found women as beautiful as Job’s daughters, and their father granted them an inheritance along with their brothers.
>
> <sup>**16**</sup> After this, Job lived a hundred and forty years; he saw his children and their children to the fourth generation. <sup>**17**</sup> And so Job died, an old man and full of years.

In the book of Job, inheritance is the test, which after a stern rebuke by god, Job passed. He shared his inheritance freely and it generated blessings.

So, Philips 4 daughters being prophets is an example of what Peter declared at the beginning of acts that the holy spirit would be poured out on all people, as prophesied by Joel the prophet (Acts 2:14-18)

> <sup>**14**</sup> Then Peter stood up with the Eleven, raised his voice and addressed the crowd: “Fellow Jews and all of you who live in Jerusalem, let me explain this to you; listen carefully to what I say. <sup>**15**</sup> These people are not drunk, as you suppose. It’s only nine in the morning! <sup>**16**</sup> No, this is what was spoken by the prophet Joel:
>
> <sup>**17**</sup> “‘In the last days, God says, I will pour out my Spirit on all people. Your sons and daughters will prophesy, your young men will see visions, your old men will dream dreams. <sup>**18**</sup> Even on my servants, both men and women, I will pour out my Spirit in those days, and they will prophesy.

So including the mention of Philip's daughters is a way of highlighting that God's kingdom is to be based generous, inclusive, and based on a sense of God's abundance.

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics.SE and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803).